# How should I connect Room, LiveData and ContentProvider?

Tags: android, android-room, android-contentprovider, android-livedata, android-cursor

### Problem

I am implementing ContentProvider for the sake of knowing how to use ContentProvider in my sample app. The scenario is as follows (two modules for my project): I have a **main module** that allows writing and reading to the database and a **consumer module** that allows only reading of the database. The database will be exposed to the **consumer module** using ContentProvider.

In my main app, I use a [Repository](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-repository/#8) to expose the methods in my Room's DAO to retrieve `LiveData` objects. An example of one such DAO.

```
interface FavoriteUserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM ${FavoriteUserColumns.TABLE_NAME}")
    fun getFavoriteUsers(): LiveData<List<FavoriteUser>>
    ...
}
```

I will use the `LiveData` to update my main app's `RecyclerView`. The problem arises when I want to use that DAO to query from the `ContentProvider` class for my consumer app (I planned to use it in the `query` method). `query` only accepts a return value of `Cursor?`. Here's my `ContentProvider` class.

```
class FavoriteUserProvider : ContentProvider() {
    private lateinit var roomDatabase: FavoriteUserRoomDatabase

    override fun onCreate(): Boolean {
        context?.let {
            val context = it
            roomDatabase = FavoriteUserRoomDatabase.getDatabase(context)
        }
        return true
    }

    override fun query(
        uri: Uri, projection: Array<String>?, selection: String?,
        selectionArgs: Array<String>?, sortOrder: String?
    ): Cursor? {
        val context = context ?: return null
        when (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            FAVORITE_USER_LIST -> {
                ... // How should I get the LiveData object here?
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

As can be seen, I can't simply use the DAO there.

---

### Question

1. Should I define a new DAO that returns a Cursor object just for my `ContentProvider` **or** should I query by using `MyRoomDatabase.openHelper.readableDatabase.query(...)`?
2. After getting the Cursor object from my `ContentProvider` class, do I have to manually map the Cursor object to my data class (for consumer app's consumption), or does Room provide a convenience method for that?
3. The Cursor object returned is not a LiveData. In my main app, when data updates happen, the `RecyclerView` is automatically notified because it's observing the LiveData. How can I do the same with a Cursor object, or is there another class that I should be aware of that can monitor cursor changes?

Answer (score 0):

you can get livedata there by this

```
    class FavoriteUserProvider : ContentProvider() {
    private lateinit var roomDao: FavoriteUserDao

    override fun onCreate(): Boolean {
        context?.let {
            val context = it
            roomDao = FavoriteUserRoomDatabase.getDatabase(context).roomDao()//ur abstract Dao
        }
        return true
    }

    override fun query(
        uri: Uri, projection: Array<String>?, selection: String?,
        selectionArgs: Array<String>?, sortOrder: String?
    ): Cursor? {
        val context = context ?: return null
        when (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            FAVORITE_USER_LIST -> {
                ... // u can get livedata here by 
                 roomDao.getFavoriteUsers().obseve(lifecycleOwner,Observer{users ->
                    // you can use matrixCursor to build cursor here
                     
                })
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: How do you use a matrixCursor to build a cursor? Furthermore, won't I be returning a Cursor still and thus my consumer app isn't really listening to Cursor changes?

Comment: https://medium.com/@xabaras/creating-a-cursor-from-a-list-with-matrixcursor-ab71877ecf2c try this